# Swift 2 & OpenCV - Result image get rotated

Tags: ios, opencv, swift2

I have added to my project the `OpenCV` framework in order to get the edge of an `UIImage`.
I have managed to get the framework working however, the converted image is rotated. How could I solve this issue?

```
// MARK: START CAMERA
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            rowImage.image = pickedImage

            ConvertImage(rowImage.image!)

        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

//MARK: CONVERT IMAGE
func ConvertImage(image: UIImage) {

        let MyImage = image
        let egeimage = EfectOpenCV.DetectEdgeWithImage(MyImage)

        CVimage.image = egeimage

}
```

OPENCV:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "openCV_test-Bridging-Header.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/highgui/ios.h>

@implementation EfectOpenCV : NSObject
+(UIImage *)DetectEdgeWithImage:(UIImage *)image{
    //UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat cvMat;
    UIImageToMat(image,cvMat);

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(cvMat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat edge;
    cv::Canny(gray, edge, 20, 80);
    UIImage *edgeImg = MatToUIImage(edge);
    return edgeImg;
}
@end
```

[image]